# retrieve variables from php and send to a js function via AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve the response from the php file im posting to and then send them to a js function please.

I also have a animated gif image in the script which doesnt show the animation. Can anyone get this working too?

the php response is in this format variable1=blabla&varaibale2=blabla

```
function sendPixelData(e:MouseEvent):void {
      capture_mc.visible = false;
 send_mc.visible = false;

    txtReturn.htmlText="Uploading Image......<img src="loading.gif" /><br/> Please Wait!";
    var output:String = "";
    var col = "";
    for (var i:Number=0; i<bitmapData.height; i++) {
        for (var j:Number=0; j<bitmapData.width; j++) {
            col = bitmapData.getPixel(j,i).toString(16);
            // In some cases, the color will be truncated (e.g. "00FF00" becomes "FF00")  
            // so we are adding the missing zeros.  
            while (col.length<6) {
                col = "0" + col;
            }
            output += col;
        }
    }
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("GetPixelData.php");
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var myURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    variables.pixels=output;// all image pixel
    //trace("output" + output)
    variables.width=videoPreviewWidth;// video width
    variables.height=videoPreviewHeight;// video height
    request.data=variables;
    request.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
    myURLLoader.addEventListener ("complete", onC);
    myURLLoader.load (request);
    function onC (e) {

         var result:String = 
      ExternalInterface.call( "redirectToURL(send variables here)" );
        trace ("save complete");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result from PHP is stored in the data property of the URLLoader, so to retrieve it use:

```
function onC (e:Event) {
    var result:String = String(e.target.data);
    ...etc
```

For part 2 of your question, Flash doesnt support gif file format - you need to use jpg or png.

BTW, dont use strings for event types - use the event type constant, eg:

```
myURLLoader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, onC);
```